# Regular expression to validate an Australian bank BSB number (XXX-XXX)?

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regex for validating a BSB number which is in the format of 3 digits, a dash, and 3 digits (e.g. 123-456).

I thought /[1-9]{3}-{1}[1-9]{3}/ would work, but it doesn't. Can someone show me which regex I need to match the BSB format?

Comment: FYI, the counter in `-{1}` is redundant. How does your regex not work? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Zero is in fact allowed for BSB codes, and the dash is optional. I would probably use `/\d{3}-?\d{3}/`, or `/[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{3}/`. That said, your given regex should definitely match a number like `123-456`, so if it's not I would investigate that (e.g. are the `/`'s part of the regex?).

A failing code snippet would be extremely helpful here, in many cases @Phil's regex would be more correct. As the question is given it's hard to tell.

Comment: I'd throw in some start and end anchors, ie `/^\d{3}-?\d{3}$/`

Comment: ... or at least some word boundaries (`\b`) otherwise you could match `1234-5678`

Comment: Correct about the zero's. I missed that. As for the reason my regex wasn't working is because I wasn't using the online regex tester properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this expression

`^\d{3}-?\d{3}$`

matches:

`123-456`

`123456`

Java version: `^\\d{3}-?\\d{3}$`

Answer (score 1):

this will allow to use space as well.

`\d{3}(-?|\s?)\d{3}`

matches:

`123-456`

`123456`

`123 456`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one to validate a BSB number with/ without a hyphen and space(s).

```
/^(?:\s*\d{3}\s*\-?\s*\d{3}\s*)$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/ge6viX/1

This would validate the following:

`023056`

`023 056`

`023 056`

`023  056`

`023-056`

`023 - 056`

`023  -  056`

`023- 056`

`023 -056`

Comment: If you do not think that this is an answer to the question at the top of this page, why do you post it here where only answer to that question are accepted? Especially since you are obviously very aware. Please delete this.

Comment: It's not directly the answer because the OP wanted to specifically match a BSB with a hyphen at index 3. While the regex I posted can do that, it can do more. Databases often contain valid BSB numbers with and without hyphen and spaces. That's why I thought this might be relevant and come in handy for some.

Comment: I actually agree wiht you, but then you should have not posted. On the other hand, seeing that there are several answers which did not care about that and still were upvoted, I assume that this kind of actually reading the question is not required here.... Strange. You would have my respect if you apply a higher level of quality to your post than the others and delete it. But in this context I decided to just remove your "this is not an answer".

Comment: If you could explain about the additional matching (beyond what is asked), or maybe adapt to actually answer the question as asked, maybe as an alternative; maybe explain the advantage of your solution over the existing answers ... that would make your answer stand out in positive way.